# manage backups azure sql option

Tags: backup, azure-sql-database, azure

This may be a silly question but I recently created an azure sql database and I need to check the backup policy but I cannot find the option *manage backups* that the documentation shows as you can see in the next picture:

[image]

and this is how the blade of my database look like

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot appears to be the SQL Database blade, not the Server blade. If you open the Overview pane on the Database blade, then in the top-right corner there is a property called **Server Name** with a link. Click the link to open the Server blade and your **Manage Backups** option is there.

Comment: thank you very much